# Customize cells Table react-virtualized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized, react-dnd

I'm using Table from '*react-virtualized*'. 
Everything is working great.

I customized my row with **rowRenderer** to add '*react-dnd*' and let my row able to being drag.

My question is about cells. Is it possible to customize them ? Like usesome React Component as Dropdown inside cells ?

Everything is store inside {**columns**} props, but no idea how to use it.

Thanks a lot for this amazing lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is about cells. Is it possible to customize them ?

Yes. You can specify a `cellRenderer` for any `Column` as shown [in the docs](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Column.md#cellrenderer).

```
function ({
  cellData: any,
  columnData: any,
  dataKey: string,
  isScrolling: boolean,
  rowData: any,
  rowIndex: number
}): node
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks